# Querying Full-Text search JsonB

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a table which I need to use full text search to filter data by multiple keywords. It works fine when I'm filtering by columns with datatypes such as varchar, int, timestamp... But when it comes to jsonb, it does not work.

My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE public.channel_jobs
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 ),
    reference_date date NOT NULL,
    creation_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    completion_datetime timestamp without time zone,
    has_alerts boolean NOT NULL,
    archived boolean NOT NULL,
    channel jsonb NOT NULL,
    index jsonb NOT NULL,
    country_id smallint NOT NULL,
    status character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    creator character varying(200) NOT NULL,
    notes text,
    CONSTRAINT channel_jobs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT channel_jobs_creator_check CHECK (btrim(creator::text) <> ''::text)
)
```

The channel and index columns have the following design:

```
{ "id": 11, "name": "blah" }
```

And the query I'm trying to execute for filtering by multiple keywords is:

```
SELECT id, reference_date, creation_datetime, completion_datetime, status, channel, index 
   FROM ( 
   SELECT id, reference_date, creation_datetime, completion_datetime, status, 
   jsonb_extract_path_text(channel, 'name') AS channel, jsonb_extract_path_text(index, 'name') AS index, 
   to_tsvector(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(8))) || 
   to_tsvector(CAST(reference_date AS VARCHAR(16))) || 
   to_tsvector(CAST(creation_datetime AS VARCHAR(22))) || 
   to_tsvector(CAST(completion_datetime AS VARCHAR(22))) || 
   to_tsvector(status) || 
   to_tsvector(jsonb_extract_path_text(channel, 'name')) || 
   to_tsvector(jsonb_extract_path_text(index, 'name')) AS document 
   FROM channel_jobs
   WHERE archived = false 
   AND country_id = 2 
   GROUP BY id, reference_date, creation_datetime, completion_datetime, status, 
   jsonb_extract_path_text(channel, 'name'), jsonb_extract_path_text(index, 'name')) AS search 
   WHERE search.document @@ to_tsquery('blah & complete')
```

If I remove `blah` from `to_tsquery()` function, it works fine and fast! But adding the index or channel name makes it fail.

Does anyone have experienced something when querying a jsonb?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? Did you try `to_tsvector("index")` or `to_tsvector(channel)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using version 4.6. Also have tried as you mentioned but does not work too.

Comment: There is no version 4.6 of Postgres (most likely it's the version of the SQL client you are using). What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: Sorry I got the pgAdmin version. It is 10.8

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d11a1ec25d0e2a8997d10bc7d271b533)

Comment: This is odd, still does not works on my query...

Comment: Try starting with a "document" that only uses one or two columns. The add the other columns until it breaks. Then investigate why the data in those columns doesn't fulfill your conditions.

Comment: OK, I got what is wrong. `blah` is just an example, but channel name can be anything. If I input not the complete channel name, it fails. When I change to the whole name, works. Is there any way to do it like a `LIKE`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name, this is how I could solve the issue:

```
SELECT id, reference_date, creation_datetime, completion_datetime, status, 
  channel, index, archived, country_id, creator, notes, has_alerts 
  FROM ( 
     SELECT id, reference_date, creation_datetime, completion_datetime,
     status, archived, country_id, channel, index, creator, notes, has_alerts,
      to_tsvector(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(8))) || 
      to_tsvector(CAST(reference_date AS VARCHAR(10))) || 
      to_tsvector(CAST(creation_datetime AS VARCHAR(22))) || 
      to_tsvector(CAST(completion_datetime AS VARCHAR(22))) || 
      to_tsvector(status) || 
      to_tsvector(channel) || 
      to_tsvector(index) AS document 
  FROM channel_jobs
  WHERE archived = false 
  AND country_id = 1
  GROUP BY id, reference_date, creation_datetime, completion_datetime, status, 
  channel, index, creator, notes) AS search 
  WHERE search.document @@ to_tsquery('complete:* & newyork:*')
```